# Matriz (Criar 2 Matrizes e Soma-las)

Tags: python-3.x

Como poderia construir esta matriz sem utilizar o random/randit? Depois preciso fazer a função soma elemento a elemento, das duas primeiras. A soma deve ser resolvida via subprograma escrito para esse fim. Este subprograma deve receber como parâmetros apenas as duas matrizes de entrada e retornar a matriz resultante caso seja possível avaliar a soma, ou None, caso não seja possível. Após retorno do subprograma, o programa principal deve exibir o conteúdo da matriz obedecendo o formato apresentado na construção da matriz. Caso None seja retornado, o programa principal deve emitir a mensagem “Não é possível somar matrizes de dimensões diferentes”.

```
#Contrução da Matriz 1 e Matriz 2 - Programa Principal
import random
matriz1 = []
n = int(input("Informe a quantidade de linhas\n da matriz 1:" ))
m = int(input("Informe a quantidade de colunas\n da matriz 1:" ))
for i in range(n):
     matriz1.append([])
     for j in range(m):
        matriz1[i].append(random.randint(0,100))

for i in range(len(matriz1)):
    for j in range(len(matriz1[i])):
        print(matriz1[i][j], end=" ")
    print ("\n")


matriz2 = []
n = int(input("Informe a quantidade de linhas\n da matriz 2:" ))
m = int(input("Informe a quantidade de colunas\n da matriz 2:" ))

for i in range(n):
     matriz2.append([])
     for j in range(m):
        matriz2[i].append(random.randint(0,100))

for i in range(len(matriz2)):
    for j in range(len(matriz2[i])):
        print(matriz2[i][j], end=" ")
    print ("\n")
```

Comment: Precisa de fazer isto com o mesmo resultado mas sem usar a função random? É essa a unica alteração a fazer?

Comment: sim.... retirar o random/randit...... e fazer a função soma que não estou conseguindo...fiz esta, mas não roda..

def somarMatrizes(matriz1, matriz2):
    if len(matriz1)!= len(matriz2):
        print ("Não é possivel somar matrizes de dimensões diferentes")
        return None                
    matriz_soma = []
    for i in range(len(matriz1)):
        matriz_soma.append([])
        for j in range(len(matriz1)):
            matriz_soma[i].append( matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j])
    return matriz_soma
print (somarMatrizes)

Comment: @ Miguel ...... Poderia auxiliar_me nesta tambem? Continuando o que fiz?

def somarMatrizes(matriz1, matriz2): if len(matriz1)!= len(matriz2): print ("Não é possivel somar matrizes de dimensões diferentes") return None matriz_soma = [] for i in range(len(matriz1)): matriz_soma.append([]) for j in range(len(matriz1)): matriz_soma[i].append( matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j]) return matriz_soma print (somarMatrizes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para somar as matrizes pode fazer:

```
def somarMatrizes(matriz1, matriz2):
    if(len(matriz1) != len(matriz2) or len(matriz1[0]) != len(matriz2[0])):
        return None
    result = []
    for i in range(len(matriz1)):   
        result.append([])
        for j in range(len(matriz1[0])):
            result[i].append(matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j])
    return result
```

Para fazer utilização disto na ultima linha do código pode fazer:

```
soma = somarMatrizes(matriz1, matriz2) # soma e o nosso retorno, result
if soma is not None:
    for i in soma:
        print(i)
else:
    print('Matrizes devem conter o mesmo numero de linhas e colunas')
```

Comment: o print sera print(somarMatrizes, end=" ") ?

Comment: Deculpe, vou fazer um acrescento

Comment: Muitissimo Obg!!!!!

Comment: De nada @ABSoares. Acho que devia alterar o titulo sendo assim, pois o a resolução do problema acabou por não envolver a não utilização do random. E se realmente a resposta o ajudou pode aceita-la, à esquerda da resposta, por baixo da seta para baixo

Comment: percebi, vou alterar de acordo

Comment: Editado @ABSoares

Comment: Sim, mas a segunda parte da resposta já não dentro do metodo (função) @ABSoares

Comment: OK entendi! Vlw!!!!!!!!! @Miguel

Comment: Ainda bem que resolveu @ABSoares. sugiro dar uma olhadela aqui, e ainda por cima recebe reputação ao ver isto até ao fim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour